# Spring batch:Test case for Tasklet - Key is not appearing in actual class when it is invoked from Test class

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I am trying to learn Batch and Tasklet.

I am writing a test case for a Tasklet code in spring batch. I am setting a map in my Test class and debug, the actual class is not having the key which I am passing from my test class.

**MyEventTasklet.java**

```
public class MyEventTasklet implements Tasklet {
    public RepeatStatus execute (StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext){

    TreeMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Student>>> studentMap = chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get("keyOfStudentMap");

 }   
    }
```

**MyEventTaskletTest.java**

```
         @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
            public class MyEventTaskletTest{

            @Mock
            StepContribution stepContribution;

            @Mock
            ChunkContext chunkContext;

            @Mock
            StepContext stepContext;

            @InjectMocks
            MyEventTasklet myEventTasklet = new MyEventTasklet();

            @Test
            public void testExecute(){

            TreeMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Student>>> studentMap = new TreeMap<>();
            Map<Integer, Set<Student>> m2 = new TreeMap<>();
            m2.put(100, createStudentData());

            studentMap.put("keyOfStudentMap", m2);

            Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<>();
            map.put("keyOfStudentMap", new Object());

            chunkContext = Mockito.mock(ChunkContext.class);
            stepContribution = Mockito.mock(StepContribution.class);
            stepContext = Mockito.mock(StepContext.class);

            Mockito.when(stepContext.getJobExecutionContext()).thenReturn(map);
            Mockito.when(chunkContext.getStepContext()).thenReturn(stepContext);
            Mockito.when(chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get("keyOfStudentMap"))
            .thenReturn((TreeMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Student>>>)studentMap);

        // When I am debugging I can see here, the studentMap object which is having something like {keyOfStudentMap={100=[StudentObject]}}, 
but when I see in actual class it is becoming {100=[StudentObject]}

     }

 }
```

I am not sure why this is happening, I am doing something wrong? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
Mockito.when(stepContext.getJobExecutionContext()).thenReturn(map);
```

`map` is not an `ExecutionContext`. You should be mocking/stubbing an `ExecutionContext` instance and not a `Map<String, Object>` instance. Your tasklet should be calling:

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()
```

instead of:

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext()
```