# Spring Batch: How to cast stepContext.getJobExecutionContext() into custom Map implementation in mockito when then

Tags: java, collections, casting, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

This question is related to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600546/spring-batchtest-case-for-tasklet-key-is-not-appearing-in-actual-class-when-i). Why I am asking here and not updating the question, because this can be helpful question and not related to the previous one which I have asked.

In a Test class how I can cast the below implementation:
Lets say I have a map like this: `TreeMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Student>>>`

and I want to cast the default `chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext()` which is `Map<String, Object>` to `TreeMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Student>>>` in my Test class.

Existing implementation is:

```
Mockito.when(chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get("keyOfStudentMap"))
            .thenReturn((TreeMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Student>>>)studentMap);
```

when I hover in `getJobExecutionContext()`, it shows `Map<String, Object>` and want to change in a way where this can changed to `TreeMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Student>>>`

Sorry if anything is unclear. I can update the question based on your comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext()
```

you need to use:

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()
```

which returns an instance of `ExecutionContext`.

Now whatever you put as key in `ExecutionContext`, you get is as is when calling `get` and hence you can cast it to the original type (`TreeMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Student>>>` in your case).